# Excel function / If value in cell XY is equal to a value in range XY:YX

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am now looking for a solution to this problem for hours and loosing my mind.

I want to go through a list and check if the text in cell D equals one in range $N$2:$N$90. If yes it should return 1, else 0.

How am I able to check this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=if(iferror(match(D1,$N$2:$N$90,0),0)>0,1,0)
```

Then drag down for all the cells in column D you want to check

This is just an example as the cells don't match:
[image]

E53 has the working function, F53 shows the function.

Comment: You are my hero! It works very well. I literally spent 4 hours to figure out but nothing worked until now.

Comment: My pleasure, glad it helps.